# Alternative to tf.records? To train a CNN in tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow, neural-network, google-cloud-platform, conv-neural-network

Im training a CNN in tensorflow using google cloud, I have a lot of images, and  when I do a tf.record the size of that record is huge, So exists another alternative to feed the data to my model??? Thankyou

Comment: You are going to need to split the images into several files

Comment: But then How do I train? I can't found an example with multiple records, if you know please help me

Comment: I am not sure what interface you are using, but you should just be able to pass multiple files in a list, the same way that you pass a single file.  See [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/datasets#consuming_tfrecord_data).